# How to make this Python Pattern?

Tags: python

```
n=int(input())
#count number
cn=0

for i in range(n):
    if n<=4:
        for j in range(i+1):
            print(cn,end="")
            cn+=1
    else:
        for j in range(0,1,n):
            print(i,end="")

    print()
```

i have this code and it should make this pattern when the input is 5

```
0
12
345
6789
01234
```

but if the input is 4 the pattern should look like this

```
0
12
345
6789
```

i have figured out if the input is 4 but i don't figured out if the input is 5
can anyone help me figured out this?

Comment: Okay, so in your own words, why do you think you need to check whether `n<=4`? Why can't you use the same logic for both patterns?

Comment: n=int(input())
#count number
cn=0

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i+1):
        print(cn,end="")
        cn+=1

    print()
it should look like this right? i have tried this code but i still didn't figured out it

Comment: if i input 5 the output is different from the example above

Comment: Okay, and *how* does it differ from the expected output? Can you explain why it differs in that way?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: Please see [How to Ask a Homework Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).  Simply dumping your assignment here is not acceptable.

Comment: Also check [can someone help me?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to check if n <= 4. There is no special case whether n is less than or greater than 4. In addition your n = 5 case notice here

```
        for j in range(0,1,n):
```

Range when supplied with three parameters works by start value, end value, and step amount. This will always only run the loop once.

Break down the problem into doable steps. First make the loop for every line in the program. Then make a loop for how many characters are going to be on that line. Finally fill those characters in by using count number (cn % 10) will allow us to wrap around from 9 back to 0.

```
n = int(input())
cn = 0 #count number

for i in range(n + 1): # For each line
    for j in range(i): # For each character in the line
        print(cn % 10, end = "")
        cn += 1
    print()
```

In general it is a good idea to avoid special cases when you are working out a solution. It can be tempting to handle input of 1, 2, 3, and so on separately but you can't physically handle every possible input ever this way

Answer (score 0):

```
K=0

for i in range(int(input())):
    for _ in range(i+1):
        print(f"{K%10}", end="")
        K+=1
    print()
```

Can do it like this